# Batch add character to variable if it has only 1 number behind dot

Tags: batch-file, floating-point, numbers, addition

I want to add 0 behind numbers fe. ".4" or "12.4" into ".40" "12.40", but only when it's one number behind dot. If it's "12.45" I want it to stay 
"12.45" It's in batch.

Comment: `if "%num:~-2,1%" equ "." set "num=%num%0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "num=12.4"
IF %num:*.=1% lss 100 SET "num=%num%0"
ECHO %num%

SET "num=12.43"
IF %num:*.=1% lss 100 SET "num=%num%0"
ECHO %num%

SET "num=12.00"
IF %num:*.=1% lss 100 SET "num=%num%0"
ECHO %num%

SET "num=12.0"
IF %num:*.=1% lss 100 SET "num=%num%0"
ECHO %num%


GOTO :EOF
```

replace all up to and including `.` with `1` - the result must be >99 if there are two dps.